# What is the meaning of 'Austenian'?

Tags: meaning

Yesterday evening the other half and I took a delightful drive into the countryside about 30 miles away, and sat for a while in the Hampshire village of Chawton (whilst listening on the car radio to the commentary from the Centre Court where Heather Watson almost defeated Serena Williams.) It was a gloriously bright summer's evening, lambs bounding in the fields around the parish church and Chawton Hall, the Elizabethan mansion once owned by Jane Austen's brother - and model for the great house described in various of Jane's novels. I commented that the countryside looked *Austenian* for it did undoubtedly bring to mind scenes from such as *Pride & Prejudice*.

But then I thought again. My own enduring criticism of Jane Austen, is that her wonderfully articulated prose is obsessed with the drawing-room manners of the lesser gentry. And this was written at the time of the Napoleonic Wars - whilst the poorer classes of Britain, in her nascent industrialisation, were being treated with the most brutal disregard - transportations, hangings, floggings, imprisonment under the Combinations Acts, filth, squalor and disease in the new towns and cities etc.

So my feeling is that the word *Austenian* should be reserved to describe those people who continue to drink tea with their little fingers extended, but blind to the mayhem all around them.

Is this unfair on Jane Austen?

Comment: Austenien makes me think of what was in the books not some blindness to social situations. Dickensian doesn't mean 'contemptuous of the nobility' even though one might infer that of some characters.

Comment: You think that's unfair?  Have you read *Pride and Prejudice and Zombies*?

Comment: @deadrat I haven't read it but I have seen it reviewed. Quite unnecessary I should have thought. One could have made a similar point almost, by juxtaposing Austen with a contemporary writer such as William Cobbett, or the later Dickens.

Comment: I see someone has voted to close, on the basis that it is 'primarily opinion based'. Shame to live in the world of 2015 when you are not meant to hold opinions, or worse still debate them!

Comment: If your question was merely to introduce an opinion about Jane Austen, then the vote to close would be appropriate.  Your last sentence might me misleading.  I understood you to ask what the meaning of "Austenian" should be as a parallel to "Dickensian."  Which is entirely appropriate for this forum.  In my opinion, of course.

Comment: Do you mean William Cobbett, Vampire Hunter?

Comment: I mean [William Cobbett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Cobbett) author of among many other things *Rural Rides*. As regards 'opinions', I find the prohibition of such is not confined to this site. There is nothing that brings on feelings of insecurity in people like the expression of other's opinions.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, but off-topic here. It is better suited to a discussion-style forum.

Comment: It needs to be noted that there are fairly large organizations, both in Britain and the US, who regularly get together in parties and conventions to dress, act, and talk in "Austen style".  I would consider a member of such a group to be an "Austenian".  Of course, the word can also be used as an adjective for either Austen's style of writing or the culture depicted in her works.

Comment: Can you change your question to ask "*How* is 'Austenian' used?" (if indeed it is) rather than "*How should* 'Austenian' be used?", please? The first can be answered objectively, with evidence; the latter is POB and will be closed (and that has nothing to do with the year, and everything to do with this specific site and its aims).

Comment: *Austenian* is no different from *Hemingwegian* or *Orwellian* or *Dickensian*. The form refers to traits, manners, themes, etc that are generally recognized as characteristic of the author. Once one has strayed into areas where there is no consensus opinion or where there is considerable debate (e.g. Jane Austen's Tory politics) then one doesn't use this sort of shorthand.

Comment: @TimRomano And we can decide for ourselves what those 'traits, manners, themes etc.' are. No argument there.

Comment: @Mitch Does Dickens engage with "the nobility"? I can't think of any such character. Most of his better-off personalities seem to me to be in the merchant class, shopkeepers, etc; or the legal profession, magistrates, schoolteachers, etc - the urban bourgeoisie and their hangers-on.